# Color effect on video in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

How is it possible to set multiple color effects on a video when it is playing ? 
Just like Instagram. I've used core image framework to give  effects on images. But I have no idea how to do same for videos. I'll not prefer to use any third party SDK.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The CoreImage framework can also process a video input.

This Apple sample project will even show you how to save a filtered video stream while displaying the preview: [Core Image Filters with Photos and Video for iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/CIFunHouse/Introduction/Intro.html)